# Chrome browser history service

Tags: web-services, google-chrome, browser-history

In Google Chrome, I can sync my browser history across multiple devices. Presumably then there is a Google web service which is used to share this browser history; is this a publicly accessible service? If so, how would I query it?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a web service rather than a js API. Presumably this would be whatever service is called by the chrome js API?